# Install the event filter for QAbstractScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt

Why we cannot install an event filter for `QAbstractScrollArea` normal way:

```
obj->installEventFilter(this)
```

Instead, we should install event filter on `QAbstractScrollArea::viewport()`. Why leads to this manner?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think you can not install an event filter on `QAbstractScrollArea`?
You can, but it depends on what event you want to get, that of the viewport or that of the `QAbstractScrolArea`.

For example documentation about `void QAbstractScrollArea::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *e)` says:

> `contextMenuEvent`event handler can be reimplemented in a subclass to receive context menu events for the viewport() widget.

So by installing an event filter in `QAbstractScrollArea` you should receive this event. However when you want to receive mouse press or mouse move events within your viewport widget, you should install an event filter in your viewport widget.